# Method POST not working with datetime-local fields

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get two datetime-local fields from a HTML form and insert them in a SQL database and they're not getting inserted.
**user-stardate** and **user-enddate** are the **datetime-local** fields, and I cannot get neither **user-totalhours** which is the difference between enddate - startdate.

```
<form role="form" action="sendFdata.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="user-role">            
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="user-pm">  
    <select name="user-project">
      <option>Text1</option>    
      <option>Text2</option>
      <option>Text3</option>                        
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="user-agroup">
    <input type="text" name="user-task">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="datetime-local" name="user-startdate">
   <input id="end-time" type="datetime-local" name="user-enddate">
   <input type="text" name="user-totalhours" placeholder="Total Hours">             
  </div>
  <div class="rule"></div>
  <div class="form-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="button-submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","")  or die("failed to connect to 
server !!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"test");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$userRole=$_POST['user-role'];
$userPM=$_POST['user-pm'];
$userProject=$_POST['user-project'];
$useraGroup=$_POST['user-agroup'];
$userTask=$_POST['user-task'];
$userStartDate=$POST['user-startdate'];
$userEndDate=$POST['user-enddate'];
$userTotalHours=$POST['user-totalhours'];

$insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `test`.`persons`
(`UserName`, `Role`, `PM`, `Product`, `ActivityGroup`, `Task`, `StartDate`, 
`EndDate`, `TotalHours`) VALUES ('$username', '$userRole', '$userPM', 
'$userProject', '$useraGroup', '$userTask', '$userStartDate', '$userEndDate', 
'$userTotalHours')";
mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You have `$POST['user-startdate']`, where it should be `$_POST['user-startdate']`.

But aside from that, you should **definitly** use prepared statements to make sql queries. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5905665)

Answer (score 0):

First datetime-local is not a correct HTML attribute for type, you should use date or time.

see it there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Then your mysql statements are a security risk since you are not using prepared statement. You should look into it.

Finally, you should debug de the request before sending it to your database.

Comment: `datetime-local` is a type for input in HTML5. Even your link says that...

Comment: oh well I knew about date and time but not datetime TIL. I think you have the correct answer with the $POST.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for the elements type "datetime-local" does not create data to be read and inputed.  Especially if viewed with Firefox or IE12 (and earlier).  It is an input the user on the page must enter a date and time into.

Assuming you are utilizing the input correctly.  What data type is your column in your database?  It must be able to handle '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as that is the restricted input that must be stored.